# Initialization failure on MobileFirst Custom Authentication

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst

When testing my IBM MobileFirst 7.1 Application with a custom Login Module against a server, I am getting the following log:

> [6/15/16 13:21:47:785 COT] 000000f3 LoginContext  W com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext invokeLoginModule FWLSE0239W: Authentication failure in realm 'CustomAuthenticatorRealm': com.httpclient.AuthClient (initialization failure) [project MyProject]

I understand that Authentication failure is a very common log. However, I would like to know if anyone knows about the meaning of (initialization failure) part. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really provide anything to base an investigation after, like which device this is (Android or iOS or?), what is the app type (hybrid or native), how did you implement your custom authentication class and so on...

From what it seems, this specific error may happen when there is a conflict between different http clients. If you are using several, then use only the one bundled by IBM Mobilefirst. If you are not, then provide much more information and more complete logs.